# Handling Json Request in php sent by alamofire

Tags: php, json, swift

I want to call my php function using alamofire and pass a json object as a parameter than handle the request inside the php function and write the data to the table.

Im using: Swift, php with laravel framework.

and what I've done so far is the following:

IN SWIFT

```
   let jsonObject: Parameters = ["isValid":true];

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost/flare/public/MyJson", method: .post, parameters: jsonObject, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
```

IN PHP

```
public function HandleJson($isValid){

    $data = json_decode($isValid);

    DB::table('FakeTable')->insert([
        'FK_ISTRUE' => $data["isValid"]]);
}
```

but It fails and since I don't have the opportunity to debug I can't figure out what to do.. any help is appreciated and excuse my bad english.

Comment: How do you verify that the post request is received by the server? What is `$isValid`?

Comment: Route::get('MyJson{isValid}','UsersController@HandleJson'); like this, I don't know how to veryfy if my request is received because the request is called in the swift environment, however if I put an echo statement  on the first statement of the function, and call the request from my browser I can see that it is received